# Entsprechender Term für "K-mer" (Englisch)

Tags: translation

Ich arbeite seit einiger Zeit an einem Essay zur algorithmischen Bearbeitung der DNA und wühle mich dabei mehr schlecht als recht durch englische Quellen, vor allem, weil ich die darin vorkommende Fachsprache oft erst übersetzen muss – meist keine leichte Aufgabe.
Dabei stolpere ich allerdings immer wieder über das Wort "K-mer". Dieses Wort kenne ich nur im Englischen. Es bezeichnet die Summe aller Teilzeichenketten (Substrings) einer Zeichenkette. Der Wikipedia-Artikel findet sich unter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer (nur auf Englisch zu finden, wohl gemerkt!).

Ich frage mich, ob es dafür auch ein entsprechendes Wort im Deutschen gibt.
Ich habe bereits alle bekannten Seiten für Übersetzungen abgeklappert und ähnliche Artikel in Deutsch durchsucht, konnte aber nichts finden. Vielleicht kennt es ja hier einer?

Comment: Guck mal hier die Suchergebnisse durch... es sieht ein bisschen so aus, als wäre der Terminus einfach k-mer   https://www.google.de/search?q=k-mer&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=k-mer&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i59j69i60.988j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=Genetik+%22k-mer%22

Comment: Zumindest gibt es die Begriffe Monomer, Dimer, etc. auch im Deutschen, also scheint der Vorschlag von @Emanuel logisch.

Comment: @Emanuel Ja, sieht ganz so aus. Da habe ich wohl nicht gründlich genug gesucht. Auf jeden Fall danke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das heißt auch auf Deutsch »K-mer« weil es sich hier um einen Fachbegriff aus dem Bereich der organischen Chemie handelt. Das Wort ist verwandt mit Polymer, Oligomer, Monomer, Dimer, Trimer, Tetramer usw.

Das Suffix mer stammt von griechischen Wort μέρος (meros) ab. Das heißt auf Deutsch: Teil.

Die verschiedenen Präfixe bedeuten:

Mono = eins
Di = zwei
Tri = drei
Tetra = vier
Oligo = wenige
Poly = viele

Es sind also Zahlwörter (bestimmte und unbestimmte). Das Präfix K in K-mer steht für eine bestimmte Zahl die aber nicht explizit angegeben ist.

Die Begriffe Monomer, Oligomer, K-mer usw. bezeichnen Moleküle, die aus einem, wenigen oder eben k gleichen (oder ähnlichen wenn es um DNA geht) Teilen bestehen.

Comment: Prinzipiell ist K kein Präfix, sondern eine Variable, die durch den Kontext festgelegt werden muss, sollte daher klein und kursiv geschrieben werden. Es steht außerdem für die Länge einer Sequenz, daher ist die Verwendung im Sinne von Dimer, Trimer, etc. nicht zu empfehlen, da es sich hier um strukturell identische Monomere handelt. Die Verwendung wir [hier](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celera_Assembler#Overlapper) demonstriert.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort, die hat dann nochmal einiges aufgeklärt. Auch danke an @Martin für den weiterführenden Kommentar.